# Configuring Attribute Tables for multiple layers using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, field-mapping

Each week I am given new ArcMap files with many Network Analyst Routes.  When I view the Attribute Table for the Stops, I am presented with 26 fields in a default order when I need to view Six of these fields in a specific order.
To avoid manually changing the Field Order for the Stops of forty or fifty Routes, how do I either, A) Set defaults for new Routes Created, or B) apply Field Order to multiple layers like can be done with applying Symbology to multiple layers?

Comment: Not sure about reordering the fields but you could certainly turn off fields by running the layer through a make feature layer tool, this would make another "view" of the same  data with you turning off the fields you don't want to see. Drop the tool in a model and run that so you never even have to remember to turn off the fields? That 50% of the way...

Comment: I think you need a small Python routine to do that.